# Why stm32 interrupt need callback function?

Tags: callback, stm32

```
   void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI0_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI0_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI0_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI0_IRQn 1 */
}

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{

}
```

Why we need a callback function instead of just writting the code in EXTI0_IRQHandler?
Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely write the code in `EXTI0_IRQHandler` directly.

The HAL provides the interrupt handlers that can do some boilerplate work for you. For example, clearing the interrupt flags, checking for errors and calling the error handlers etc.

In your case, the callback also receives the GPIO pin number that triggered the interrupt. If you wrote the hander manually, you would have to figure that out from the interrupt flags/status registers.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It just clears the related interrupt flag. If you clear it by yourself you don't need it.

Long answer: Abstraction, portability. They are keeping it for future use. If needed, future mpu with new peripherals can be handled properly...